Maximal sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebras of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$
After asking this question and finding this relevant paper, I would like to ask the following question:
For every $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, denote:
$A_{a,b}=\mathbb{C}[(x-a)(x-b),x(x-a)(x-b),y]$
and
$B_{a,b}=\mathbb{C}[(y-a)(y-b),y(y-a)(y-b),x]$.
If I am not wrong (but I may be wrong), $A_{a,b}$ and $B_{a,b}$ are maximal sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebras of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$,
namely, there is no proper sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebra $T_A$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that
$A_{a,b} \subsetneq T_A$
and there is no proper sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebra $T_B$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that
$B_{a,b} \subsetneq T_B$.

Question: I am looking for maximal sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebras of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ other than $A_{a,b},B_{a,b}$. Is it possible to describe all maximal sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebra of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ in terms of generators like $A_{a,b},B_{a,b}$?

Thank you very much!

Applying a change of coordinates (automorphism of $\mathbb C[x,y]$) will give you other algebras, similarly to how $A_{a,b}$ is obtained from $B_{a,b}$ by exchanging $x$ and $y$.

@red_trumpet, nice comment; thank you! So we can focus on $A_{a,b}$ and apply any automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ to obtain another (proper) maximal sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Are there additional (proper) maximal sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebras?

These are not maximal. For example if you add $xy$ to $A_{a,b}$ you get something which is a larger algebra but still not proper since any polynomial in the algebra takes the same value at the points $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$.
The following two types of subalgebras are codimension $1$, hence maximal: For any two points in $\mathbb C^2$, the algebra of polynomials whose values at those two are the same, or for any point in $\mathbb C^2$ and tangent vector at that point, the algebra of polynomials whose derivative at that point in that tangent direction vanishes.
Maybe these are the only maximal ones.

What if we take the above $A_{a,b}=\mathbb{C}[(x-a)(x-b),(x-a)(x-b)x,y]$ and extend it to the larger sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebra $\tilde{A_{a,b}}=A_{a,b}+\langle (x-a)(x-b),(x-a)(x-b)x,y \rangle$? I have added the ideal generated by ${(x-a)(x-b),(x-a)(x-b)x,y}$. Is the larger $\tilde{A_{a,b}}$ a proper maximal sub-$\mathbb{C}$-algebra? Notice that $xy \in \tilde{A_{a,b}}-A_{a,b}$. $x \notin \tilde{A_{a,b}}$, so it is proper. I am not sure about maximality (maybe maximality follows by the codimension $1$ argument).

Sometimes $\tilde{A_{a,b}}$ is not proper: For example, $a=1,b=-1$, $\tilde{A_{a,b}}=\mathbb{C}[x^2-1,x^3-x,y]+\langle x^2-1,x^3-x,y\rangle$. If we allow to change the generators in the algebra and accordingly in the ideal, then we get $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3-x,y]+\langle x^2,x^3-x,y \rangle$, then $x$ is in this algebra: $x=x(x^2)-(x^3-x)$. But if we do not allow such a change of generators in the ideal, then the algebra is proper.
